# Combine scatter and line charts with highcharter in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am new to **highcharter** package. I want to add a line (regression line) on a scatter chart. It seems simple enough but I cannot crack it. I can make them separately using `hchart()` but they do not merge.

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

lm.model <- augment(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))

lm.model %>%
  hchart(type = "scatter", hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg))

lm.model %>%
  hchart(type = "line", hcaes(x = wt, y = .fitted)
```

I also tried using `hc_add_series_scatter()` but I do not find a similar function for line.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series_scatter(x = lm.model$wt, y = lm.model$mpg)
```

Is it even possible to combine two chart types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(lm.model, "scatter", hcaes(wt, mpg)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(lm.model, "line", hcaes(x = wt, y = .fitted))
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! do you know how to remove the legend (Series 1 and Series 2)?

Comment: just add `showInLegend = FALSE` as argument in `hc_add_series()`